# create JSON form an array with PHP and decode it with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

if i am decoding a array with php i get JSON with brackets:

```
$data = array();
$data[0]["id"] = 23;
$data[0]["modul"] = "my modul";

echo '' .json_encode($data). '';
```

i'm getting a JSON like this:

```
[{"id":23,"modul":"my modul"}]
```

when i want this to decode with javascript there is nothing to decode cause javascript wants JSON without brackets

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(mySendJSONData);
```

i already tried to use this before parsing:

```
myObj = myObj[0];
```

but it did't solve it.

more clearly: i want to use server side events to send JSON to the client:

SERVER:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/event-stream' );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache' );

    $data = array();
    $data[0]["id"] = 23;
    $data[0]["modul"] = "my modul";

    echo 'data: ' .json_encode($data). "\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

CLIENT:

```
  var source = new EventSource("myServerSideEvent.php");

    source.onmessage = (event) => {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(event.data);     
        document.getElementById("moduldialog").innerHTML = myObj.modul;
    }
```

Comment: You're building a perfectly valid JSON representation of a *array*, which JavaScript definitely can handle. What makes you think that "there's nothing to decode"?

Comment: `myObj = myObj[0]` will only work *after* parsing, not before.  Before you parse it it's just a string.

Comment: I just ran the same code you posted here. Everything seems fine  - https://jsfiddle.net/vemn29g6/

Comment: the json is 100% valid as per an online JSON Linter (https://jsonlint.com). What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @ Pointy: when i say "nothing to decode" i mean that i'm getting a empty array.

Comment: What does `mySendJSONData` look like before you try to parse it? And do you know that `echo '' .json_encode($data). '';` is exactly the same as just `echo json_encode($data);`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt echo json_encode($data); outputs [{"id":23,"modul":"my modul"}]

Answer (score 0):

You're sending JSON-encoded data, which should be a string. But you're not delineating it as a string in the output. Try:

```
echo 'data: \'' .json_encode($data). "'\n\n";
```